# PHP: How to manipulate this array as CPU extensive as possible

Tags: php, arrays, loops

i am working on an API for internal use and my SQL query is returning me the results as an array. Now i need a certain part (the coordinates) formatted properly but i don`t get it.

I tried different for loops and things like array_splice but i always end up only almost there. The other thing is, i will run this on all results, so i need a solution which performs good. Take a look at the examples, i am thankful for any help.

I need to get from this array:

```
array (
  0 => array (
    'id' => '3',
    'name' => 'Stadthalle',
    'description' => 'Die Wiener Stadthalle',
    'created_at' => '2012-01-07 14:22:06',
    'coordinates' => '48.201187:16.334213, 48.200665:16.331606, 48.202989:16.331091, 48.203075:16.334192',
    'media' => 'image:http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4069/4679448909_1264ea4668_b.jpg,video:http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4',
  ),
  1 => array (
    'id' => '4',
    'name' => 'Schloss SchÃ¶nbrunn',
    'description' => 'Schloss SchÃ¶nbrunn, die ehemalige Sommerresidenz der Kaiserfamilie, zÃ¤hlt zu den schÃ¶nsten Barockanlagen Europas.',
    'created_at' => '2012-01-10 01:06:48',
    'coordinates' => '48.201187:16.334213, 48.200665:16.331606, 48.202989:16.331091, 48.203075:16.334192',
    'media' => 'image:http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4069/4679448909_1264ea4668_b.jpg,video:http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4',
  ),
)
```

To this array:

```
 array (
      0 => array (
        'id' => '3',
        'name' => 'Stadthalle',
        'description' => 'Die Wiener Stadthalle',
        'created_at' => '2012-01-07 14:22:06',
        'coordinates' => array(
            array('48.201187:16.334213'),
            array('48.200665:16.331606'),
            array('48.202989:16.331091'),
            array('48.203075:16.334192')
        ),
        'media' => 'image:http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4069/4679448909_1264ea4668_b.jpg,video:http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4',
      ),
      1 => array (
        'id' => '4',
        'name' => 'Schloss SchÃ¶nbrunn',
        'description' => 'Schloss SchÃ¶nbrunn, die ehemalige Sommerresidenz der Kaiserfamilie, zÃ¤hlt zu den schÃ¶nsten Barockanlagen Europas.',
        'created_at' => '2012-01-10 01:06:48',
        'coordinates' => array(
            array('48.201187:16.334213'),
            array('48.200665:16.331606'),
            array('48.202989:16.331091'),
            array('48.203075:16.334192')
        ),
        'media' => 'image:http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4069/4679448909_1264ea4668_b.jpg,video:http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4',
      ),
    )
```

Comment: You should also try to get from this data: `Schloss SchÃ¶nbrunn` to this data: `Schloss Schönbrunn`.

Comment: This will be JSON output anyway instead of PHP, when decoded it will show "Schönbrunn".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($outerArray as $key => &$value) {
    $coords = explode(',', $value['coordinates']);
    $value['coordinates'] = array();
    foreach ($coords as $coordPair) {
        $value['coordinates'][] = explode(':', $coordPair);
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thanks, i just had to switch  line 2 and 3. Can you tell me what the "&" is for? Or give me a keyword i can goolge for. Thanks!

Comment: Oops, you're right about the switch. The &amp; character tells PHP to pass a reference to the item in the array so that when we updated it in lines 3 and 5 it will carry that update back to the original array. Google 'pass by reference'.

Comment: Oh my god, that is where i failed. I tried then to store it into a $temp variable and recreate the array with array_push. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Looks simple enough:

```
foreach($array as &$item) {
    $item['coordinates'] = explode(', ', $item['coordinates']);
}
```

**[See it in action](http://www.ideone.com/L1l6n)**.

This does not actually do exactly what you show, but you can change it to

```
$item['coordinates'] = array_map(function($el) { return array($el); },
                                 explode(', ', $item['coordinates']));
```

if that's really what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you use mysql but unfortunately mysql has no concept of arrays. Maybe you can use postgres because I believe it can work with arrays. But it seems this question is a duplicate: [How to SQL Select a one to many relation and merge the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813708/how-to-sql-select-a-one-to-many-relation-and-merge-the-output).